# References can not be reinitialized after check-in from visual studio team service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I did check-in to download source code for the first time, but i got some missing references. I've tried following ways but it doesnt work for me:

- Add references: Right click -> add references then find references (after adding the references, there is nothing change, you can see in the photo below)
- Dlls were set to Copy Local (I even can not change the copy local to 
  true)
- Adding namespaces to both web.configs did nothing.

I used VS2015. is there any way to update it correctly? thanks

[image]

Comment: Those are nuget packages. You'll need nuget to download all the packages for your solution. Simply rebuilding your solution is usually enough to fix your issue.

Comment: I tried to rebuild but i canot complete because of those missing references

Comment: Probably rebuiild referencing projects??

Comment: how can i rebuild referencing projects.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, source code does not contain dll's, since they are vey big files. So I would not normally expect to get dll's from source control. You would usually have to build the solution and hope that Nuget is enabled to download the dll's from where they are stored.

However, the dll's you are showing come with the .net framework, so this should not be an issue, unless of course, the solution file is expecting to find the dll's in some /bin directory.

You can find which directory the dll's are expected to be in by right clicking on the missing dll and then clicking on 'properties'. This should show you the referenced dlls path in the properties window.

If the dll is not in that path you can do one of 2 things:

1. Delete the reference and add a new reference to the dll, where it actually exists
2. paste the dll in the path that is being referenced by the solution.

Comment: there are many missing references, is there anyways update all of them at the same time.

Comment: Not sure if there is an easier way. If they are all in the same path, you could edit the project file (ctrl-c, ctrl-v): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171487(v=vs.90).aspx